# Apache Segmentation Fault when case changes in URL with CodeIgniter

Tags: apache, codeigniter, segmentation-fault

I'm using CodeIgniter and I my controller filenames and class names are named as per documentation.

On one particular controller, when I first load it with a lowercase URL, it works fine. If I change the URL to have an initial cap, it still works. However, then going back to lowercase - the exact same URL that worked before - causes a segmentation fault in Apache.

I have deleted everything from the controller, except for an empty method, and I continue to get the same problem. I have tried on two separate servers and get the same problem, whether I go from upper to lower, or lower to upper. I have restarted both servers.

I'm also having problems getting a core dump, but that's another story. I'm just wondering if anybody recognises the issue.

EDIT:
I ended up just using lowercase with everything, and that worked.

Comment: I don't know exactly what can be happening, but posting the content of  your htaccess file can help. Edit the main post and add it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using any kind of caching on your servers? Are they stock Apache servers without any modification? What happens if you download a copy of [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) onto your local machine and run the same code, are you getting the same errors?

If you can identify if it's a server or code issue, then we can work from there.